# Can you have multiple default namespaces?

Tags: c#, namespaces, project

If I have a main project, call it MainProject, and a side project that's based out of MainProject called SideProject. Right now I've added a reference to MainProject in SideProject. but because almost all of the classes in SideProject reference some code from MainProject I have to prefix almost all of the classes in SideProject with

```
using MainProject;
```

I feel like there should be a better / more elequent way to do this that would let me state this once. Whether that's setting multiple default namespaces, or something in the App.xaml. I can't figure it out and I can't find the answer online. Does anyone know if there's an accepted convention for how to accomplish this?

Comment: How about using the same default namespace in both projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the accepted convention is to use `using MainProject;` at the top of every single source file.

If you really don't like using directives at the top of the files, you could use the same namespaces in different projects or use subnamespaces. For instances, you could use the namespace `MainProject.SideProject` in your side-project.